# Deploying a Full Stack Project to EC2 (Springboot, React)

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, amazon-ec2, devops

I am having a hard time deploying my app to an EC2 instance, I have my Jar file listening to port 8080 and my React app running on Nginx. I don't know if this is the optimal way to deploy projects and I am very new to linux. The current issue I've been having is that my crypto.randomuuid() function is not being read. Below are the screenshots of my Node and NPM versions from my localhost and from the EC2 instance.

My local Node and npm -v

PS D:\iSphereTimesheet\TimesheetClient\iiq-timesheet> node -v

v20.5.1

PS D:\iSphereTimesheet\TimesheetClient\iiq-timesheet> npm -v

10.0.0

On the instance

[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 build]$ node -v

v20.10.0

[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 build]$ npm -v

10.2.3

(changed ip to 0s for privacy)

is there anywhere else I should look as to why this doesn't work? or any other approach I could do to accomplish my goal? Thanks.